Why the SMTP Connection unexpectedly closes while trying outlook and yahoo server?
I'm validating the email with smtp server connection using rcpt command. It is working fine with google but when I try with outlook and yahoo email it shows "SMTP connection error: Connection unexpectedly closed "
my code is here
def check_smtp(self, email):
    host = socket.gethostname()
    server = smtplib.SMTP(port=self.smtp_port_number, timeout=self.connection_timeout)
    server.set_debuglevel(100)
    server.connect(self.get_MX_records(email.split('@')[1]))
    server.helo(host)
    server.mail('example@gmail.com')
    code, message = server.rcpt(str(email))
    server.quit()
    if code == 250:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Here is my input
{"email": "test@outlook.com"}

Most SMTP servers block connections from random clients. You should send the email through your ISP's relay.

Spammers abused this in the 1990s so it's turned off most places anyway. Probably they think you're a spammer, too.

It's likely because your IP is blacklisted or the SMTP handshake is not being established properly.
You can try using your home network; it might work.
Since I have developed an email verification API tool, I occasionally encounter these kinds of issues as well.
